# Native2Ascii API

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to perform the Native2Ascii Task by using the API. MY code look s like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File sourceDir = new File("c://temp//");        
    File targetDir = new File("c://temp1//");
    Native2Ascii n2a = new Native2Ascii();
    n2a.setSrc(sourceDir);
    n2a.setDest(targetDir);
    n2a.setEncoding("utf8");
    n2a.execute();
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following exception in the line n2a.execute():

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.setupDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:529)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:492)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask.getDirectoryScanner(MatchingTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.execute(Native2Ascii.java:239)
    at Native2AsciiTest.main(Native2AsciiTest.java:27)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: what's the version of this optional jar you're using?

Answer (score 2):

From Ant source code, you can see find that the Project is null:

```
public synchronized void setupDirectoryScanner(FileScanner ds, Project p) {
    if (isReference()) {
        getRef(p).setupDirectoryScanner(ds, p);
        return;
    }
    if (ds == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ds cannot be null");
    }
    ds.setBasedir(dir);

    PatternSet ps = mergePatterns(p);
    p.log(getDataTypeName() + ": Setup scanner in dir " + dir
        + " with " + ps, Project.MSG_DEBUG);
```

The NullPointerException is at `p.log`.

So you can try this for a start to get past the NullPointerException:

```
Project project = new Project();
n2a.setProject(project);
```

Then move on to the next problem...

**1. Following up on your comments**

Do you need to do this file conversion during runtime of you application? Could you use either ant build (with [native2ascii](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/native2ascii.html) task), or the JDK's [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) CLI to convert the files "off line"?

**2. Add tools.jar to classpath**

You need to have `tools.jar` from the JDK on runtime classpath. With that, I was able to run it.

Comment: Thanks @sudocode, this works but brings uo the next problem as you predicted. As this all seems to be quite complicated maybe a general question: Am I not supposed to run the task via API? I need to replace the special characters by the unicode representation and thought it might be a good idea to use the native2ascii task, but maybe I am wrong here...

Comment: Seems like all your missing now is `tools.jar`.